# How can I use a virtual audio sink on an android emulator in headless mode? Getting pulseaudio init error when launching emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, qemu, pulseaudio

I have a virtual sink on my host machine. pulseaudio is running as a system wide daemon. When trying to launch an emulator with the follow command:

`emulator -avd emulator -no-window`

I get the following output:

`pulseaudio: Failed to initialize PA contextCould not init 'pa' audio driver`

If I were to exclude `-no-window` flag, then it works without issue. How can I get my virtual sink to work on a headless android emulator?